# Execute the method of a script to a remote server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, aix

I have a script with 4-5 methods in it, the script will be running on server1. I want couple of the methods of this script to run on server2. What I tried is....

script

```
method1()
{
 df -h
}

method2()
{
 cd /path
 ls -al
}

cmd=ssh
cmd_options="-v root@dtr6-sam-cache02"
$cmd $cmd_options "method1; method2"

method3()
{
---
---
}

method4(){
}
-----
-----
```

This is the error which I am getting

```
ksh[1]: method1: not found [No such file or directory]
ksh[1]: method2: not found [No such file or directory]
```

It is not reading them as method so what should I do to make it read the method. I want to run first 2 methods on server1 then on server2 and then rest all method on server1.

NOTE: The above program is just an example the methods contain more number of lines, so I can't assign it to a variable

Comment: One can't read your mind to figure what you're looking for.  Unless you were to say something about what `methods` were supposed to do and such, there's little to offer.

Comment: Ok fine I can run a file to other server can you tell me a way that it doesnt ask for the password for server2... can I pass password directly through script1...

Answer (score 0):

copy shell scripts with the contents of method1 / method2 to server2 (e.g. via scp) and trigger their execution via ssh.

Comment: While executing ssh it is asking for server2 password, I want to provide password from the script itself, how can i do so....

Comment: the best thing is to use public key cryptography.